# Lead image uploading issue in drupal node,

Tags: image, drupal, image-processing, imagefield

In the drupal node I've one field called 'add lead image' of type image,    whenever I want to upload image sometime it's uploading sometime not.

This is strange issue for me. Can anyone help me in solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the image field settings in your content type for the allowed image types and file size and make sure they do not conflict with the images that you are trying to upload.